# Xcode NSException and NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I new to MacOS and Xcode, I have never used them before.

I have to make a simple game using Xcode for my class. I have managed to set everything up (using VirtualBox), watched some tutorial and made a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

The building is successful but when the Simulator starts my app I get an error about one of my three buttons (Paper_Button). Even if I comment the code of the button in ViewController I still get the error. I looked up in my code but nothing... I am sorry for the dumb question but I didn't seem to find any solution.

This is the error:

```
Exception   NSException *   "[<RPS.ViewController 0x7fdf76008840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PAPER_Button."   0x0000600001ab83f0
name    __NSCFConstantString *  "NSUnknownKeyException" 0x00007fff801e80a0
reason  __NSCFString *  "[<RPS.ViewController 0x7fdf76008840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PAPER_Button."   0x00006000025e8280
userInfo    __NSDictionaryI *   2 key/value pairs   0x00006000001a10c0
reserved    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x00006000014c5fc0
```

```
    //
//  ViewController.swift
//  RPS
//
//  Created by MaiorCristian on 4/21/21.
//

import UIKit

//@interface
//SettingsViewController:
//UITableViewController

//BEFORE: UIViewController
//AFTER: UITableViewController

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var player_points = 0
    var cpu_points = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CPU_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var YOU_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CPU_Image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var WINNER: UILabel!
    
    
    var playersChoice = 0;
    @IBAction func ROCK_Button(_ sender: Any) {
        playersChoice = 1
        let cpuNumberChoice = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        setCPUimage(imageView: CPU_Image, imageNumber: cpuNumberChoice)
        
        //rock 1, paper 2, scissors 3
        
        //rock - rock
        if cpuNumberChoice == 1 && playersChoice == 1 {
            //tie
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: TIE!"
        }
        //paper - rock
        if cpuNumberChoice == 2 && playersChoice == 1 {
            cpu_points = cpu_points + 1
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: CPU!"        }
        //scissors - rock
        if cpuNumberChoice == 3 && playersChoice == 1 {
            player_points = player_points + 1
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: YOU!"        }
        
        YOU_label.text = "YOU: \(player_points)"
        CPU_label.text = "CPU: \(cpu_points)"
        
    }
    
    /*@IBAction func PAPER_Button(_ sender: Any) {
        playersChoice = 2
        let cpuNumberChoice = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        setCPUimage(imageView: CPU_Image, imageNumber: cpuNumberChoice)
        
        //rock 1, paper 2, scissors 3
        
        //paper - paper
        if cpuNumberChoice == 2 && playersChoice == 2 {
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: TIE!"        }
        //scissors - papper
        if cpuNumberChoice == 3 && playersChoice == 2 {
            cpu_points = cpu_points + 1
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: CPU!"        }
        //rock - papper
        if cpuNumberChoice == 1 && playersChoice == 2 {
            player_points = player_points + 1
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: YOU!"        }
        
        YOU_label.text = "YOU: \(player_points)"
        CPU_label.text = "CPU: \(cpu_points)"
        
    }
    */
    @IBAction func SCISSORS_Button(_ sender: Any) {
        playersChoice = 3
        let cpuNumberChoice = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        setCPUimage(imageView: CPU_Image, imageNumber: cpuNumberChoice)
        
        //rock 1, paper 2, scissors 3
        
        //scissors - scissors
        if cpuNumberChoice == 3 && playersChoice == 3 {
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: TIE!"        }
        //rock - scissors
        if cpuNumberChoice == 1 && playersChoice == 3 {
            cpu_points = cpu_points + 1
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: CPU!"        }
        //paper - scissors
        if cpuNumberChoice == 2 && playersChoice == 3 {
            player_points = player_points + 1
            WINNER.text = "WINNER: YOU!"        }
        
        YOU_label.text = "YOU: \(player_points)"
        CPU_label.text = "CPU: \(cpu_points)"
        
    }
    ///

        //
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //@IBAction func

    func setCPUimage(imageView:UIImageView, imageNumber: Int){
        switch imageNumber {
        case 1://rock
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_20210421_121204_edit_267680766477383")
        case 3://scissors
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_20210421_121232_edit_267656474039366")
        case 2://paper
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_20210421_121216_edit_267673424825822")
        
        default:
            print("error")
            //imageView.image = UIImage(named: "rock")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

```
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RPS.ViewController 0x7fdf76008840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PAPER_Button.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11 (BCA23623-0F8A-46DA-BE7F-F3B81149500E) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 11
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RPS.ViewController 0x7fdf76008840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PAPER_Button.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11 (BCA23623-0F8A-46DA-BE7F-F3B81149500E) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 11
(lldb)
```

Comment: Go to Interface Builder and check if the IBAction is properly connected. By the way according to the naming convention function names are supposed to be *lowerCamelCase*.

Comment: You had a variable named `PAPER_Button`, which you created in code, in Storyboard and made the connection between the two. But you removed it later in code, but didn't remove the connection. That's why it's failing. For the rest, naming is important too, so `lowerCamelCase` is strongly suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `PAPER_Button`, which is referenced by .xib or .storyboard file, does not exist in your `ViewController` class.

I guess removing `PAPER_Button` from .xib or .storyboard file will fix the error.